# GRE Reasoning problem time/distance/average speed

Tags: gre-exam

David drove to work at an average (arithmetic mean) speed of 45 miles per hour. After work, David drove home at an average speed of 60 miles per hour. If David spent a total of 2 hours commuting to and from work, how many miles does David drive to work?

A) 48

B) $\dfrac{256}{5}$

C) $\dfrac{360}{7}$

D) $\dfrac{105}{2}$

E) $\dfrac{160}{3}$

**Solution: (C)**

**My answer:**

$\begin{align}
t_1 &=\dfrac{v_1}{d} = \dfrac{45}{d} \\
t_2 &=\dfrac{v_2}{d} = \dfrac{60}{d}
\end{align}$

and

$t = t_1 + t_2 =2$

so: 
$\hspace{5mm} d =\dfrac{105}{2} \hspace{5mm}$ **(D)**

> Apparently, my thinking is wrong, but I don't know where.
>
> Any thoughts? Very much appreciated!

Comment: Think about units. If you divide speed by distance, you have (miles/hr)/miles, so you do *not* get time. Remember that distance is speed $\times$ time (assuming constant speed).

Comment: omg!! Of course, shame on me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is slightly off- you should have $v_1\cdot t_1=d$ and $v_2\cdot t_2=d$. You can see this with units of measurement: miles per hour can be expressed as $\frac{\text{miles}}{\text{hours}}$ and time as $hours$ so there product should be distance as $miles$. If you want to verify, your answer should be $C$.

Comment: Yes of course, thank you for the prompt reply! I messed up here!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is by [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean#In_physics). Since you are given two average speeds over same distance, average speed of total travel is given by $$v = \frac{2}{\frac 1{v_1} + \frac 1{v_2}} = \frac{2}{\frac 1{45} + \frac 1{60}} = \frac{360}{7}\,\text{mph}$$

Since twice the distance from home to work takes $2$ hours at that speed, the distance is precisely $\frac{360}7$ miles.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be just to say

$t_{total} = t_{home}+t_{work} =  \frac{d_{home}}{v_{home}} +{\frac{d_{work}}{v_{work}}}$

We know that $$d_{home}=d_{work}$$

So just plug in the values and solve for d

Answer (score 0):

since the rate from home to work and from work to home has been given which are $45\mathrm{mph}$ and $60\mathrm{mph}$ respectively. 
Let x represent distance: then
$$
time = distance /rate 
$$
from home to work, $t= x/45$,
 
while from work to home $t = x/60$, where total time $= 2$ hours,  therefore 
$$
\begin{split}
x/45 + x/60 &= 2\text{ hours} \\
 60x +45x /2700 &= 2\\
5400/105 &= 51.428...
\end{split}
$$

hence from the answer options $= 360/7$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

S1=D/t1
45=D/t1
S2=D/t2
60=D/t2
t1+t2=2
Average speed=Total distance/total time taken
total time=total distance/average speed
2=D/45+D/60
solving D=360/7

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).